# Early submission to App Store to support iOS6 and iPhone 5

Tags: app-store, ios6, iphone-5

I'm preparing an update for my app to be fully compatible with iOS6 and iPhone5 display, so it would be great to submit it to the App Store before they are released to the public, to allow anyone to use enjoy it from Day1.

Apple says that developers can now submit their iOS6 optimized apps (I don't find anything about iPhone 5), but I'm asking to myself if I can - since today - write something like "iOS6 compatibility added" or "Support for iPhone 5 display" in the changelog... or they will reject my submission because I'm telling about something that is not already released/sold?

Comment: The public already know that iOS 6 and iPhone 5 exists, you're only prohibited from discussing its inner workings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that it is official, you should be able to submit it now!